# logic behind bitcoin exchange

Tags: blockchain, blockchain-wallet-app, decentralized-exchanges

Im currently working on exchange program. Just a problem during exchange process. An example, we have an SELLING LIST which list down all trading and selling of bit coin. So, in the meantime, there will be a tons of buyers to see the most appropriate and cheap sales. Give an example that there is one items from the Selling List that selling 1BTC for 1USD, so every buyer will immediately click on the item to buy the item. Hence, the question and issue is here,

Is there any effective way to tackle our program to avoid from crash as caused from multiple user clicked and accessed the item on the same?
I'm thinking about FIFO on the user access. Is there any more efficient way to tackle this issue?

Comment: If you need to ask random strangers on the internet how to build your business, you have a problem.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with bitcoin. I would strong suggest you to post it on stackoverflow *after* you show what you have tried to do thus far. You're looking for a system-design.